# Attached is not getting called on extending a base class

Tags: aurelia

**attached** is not getting called on extending a base class:

```
export class FieldBase{
  constructor() {

  }

  activate(model) {
    console.log("Inside Base Activate");
  }
}

export class FieldChild extends FieldBase{
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  attached(){
    console.log("Inside Child Attached"); //NOT WORKING
  }
  activate(model) {
   super.activate(model);
    console.log("Inside Child Activate");
  }
}
```

Here FieldChild's attached is not getting called. But if I add attached method in the FieldBase, FieldChild's attached is working. --

```
export class FieldBase{
  constructor() {

  }
  attached(){
    //added
  }
  activate(model) {
    console.log("Inside Base Activate");
  }
}
export class FieldChild extends FieldBase{
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      attached(){//overriding
        console.log("Inside Child Attached"); //WORKING
      }
      activate(model) {
       super.activate(model);
        console.log("Inside Child Activate");
      }
    }
```

WHY?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know unfortunately Aurelia currently does not support component's inheritance correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the base class must have the `attached()` method. And, if you have some code in this method, you must call it inside the `attached()` of the child class (unless if you really want to override, of course). For instance:

```
export class BaseClass {
  attached() {
    //do something
  }
}

export class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
  attached() {
    base.attached(); //call base attached!
    // do something
  }
}
```

I use inheritance in components and they work fine.